# Bad formula when using excelize Golang

Tags: excel, go, formula, excelize

I get an error when using a formula like this `[file.SetCellFormula(sheetName, "A6", "=IF(C6<>\"\";IF(OR((F6-E6)>0;G6<>\"\";J6>0);\"O\";\"X\");\"\")")]`, I'm sure the formula is correct, I have copied this formula from a working excel file

```
func excel() error {
    sheetName := "022022"

    if IsFileExists("./excels/Rikai_TimeSheet_202202_SonNguyen.xlsx") {
        err := os.Remove("./excels/Rikai_TimeSheet_202202_SonNguyen.xlsx")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    file, err := excelize.OpenFile("./excels/Rikai_TimeSheet_202202_SonNguyen_template.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        _ = file.Close()
    }()
    

    err = file.SetCellFormula(sheetName, "A6", "=IF(C6<>\"\";IF(OR((F6-E6)>0;G6<>\"\";J6>0);\"O\";\"X\");\"\")")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile("./excels/Rikai_TimeSheet_202202_SonNguyen.xlsx", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = file.Write(f)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

[Error popup when open the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Qbg.png)

Comment: Why not use raw string literals (those enclosed with backticks) in order to not backslash-escape all the double quotes?

Comment: @kostix thanks for the tip but still doesn't work

Comment: An .xlsx file is just a ZIP archive with a bunch of XML files. I'd try to narrow the problem down this way: 1) reduce your example to an absolute minimum: ideally it should contain just a single formula which still makes the document be considered corrupted by whatever piece of software you're using to open it; 2) once you'll have determined the culprit, open the generated document as an archive and extract the files from it to somewhere; 3) create the same document by hand using that reference piece of software, with the same formula. Unpack the resulting document…

Comment: ….Locate the formulae in both sets of unpacked XML files obtained from the documents and try to figure out how the way the formula is specified is different between them. Then try to work from there.

Comment: Thanks @kostix I have found the answer, It's about the comma 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing those semicolons (;) by commas (,).
(As a general idea, always use the US standards, not your local one)

Comment: Hi @Patrick Honorez 
Thanks for the help, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @SơnNguyễn see update

Comment: You just save my life @Patrick Honorez, thanks a lot 

Comment: @SơnNguyễn glad I did. Pls mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use backticks ` instead of escaping quotes:

```
err = file.SetCellFormula(sheetName, "A6", `=IF(C6<>"";IF(OR((F6-E6)>0;G6<>"";J6>0);"O";"X");"")`)
```

Comment: It's not the answer but thanks for the tip 